# Draw line and point into a BodePlot

Tags: plotting, functions, intersection

From the BodePlot function, I would like to plot the vertical line at horizontal axis equal to 10 as in the magnitude plot below and indicate the coordinate of the intersection point.

Could anyone help me to do this?

Thank you.

```
BodePlot[1/(1 + s/10 + s^2/100)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bplts = BodePlot[1/(1 + s/10 + s^2/100), 
 GridLines -> {{{10}, None}, {{10}, None}}, GridLinesStyle -> Red, 
 Mesh -> {{{10}}, {{10}}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** You can show the coordinates of the intersection by post-processing the graphics output to add `Tooltip` or `Text`:

```
(Normal /@ bplts) /. Point[p__] :> Tooltip[Point[p], p]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(Normal /@ bplts) /. 
 Point[p__] :> {Point[p], Red, Text[Style[p, 16], p, Left]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks. As the comment in David's answer, I would like to show the coordinate of intersection point something like (10, 0) on the plot. How can I do that?

Comment: @anhnha, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to understand the code. The normal function is new to me. I am reading from help section but it seems abstract.

Answer (score 5):

```
BodePlot[1/(1 + s/10 + s s/100),
 Epilog -> Line[{{1, -100}, {1, .11}}]]
```

or

```
BodePlot[1/(1 + s/10 + s s/100),
 Epilog -> {{Red, Line[{{1, -100}, {1, .11}}], 
            {PointSize[0.05], Point[{1, .11}]}}, 
            {Red, Line[{{1, -90}, {1, -200}}]}}]
```

[image]

If you want to have the points calculated automatically for your choice of abscissa:

```
mysvalue = 1;
f[s_] := 1/(1 + s/10 + s s/100);
BodePlot[f[s],
 Epilog -> {{Red, 
    Line[{{mysvalue, -100}, {mysvalue, f[mysvalue]}}], 
          {PointSize[0.05], 
    Point[{mysvalue, f[mysvalue]}]}}, 
   {Red, Line[{{mysvalue, -90}, {mysvalue, -200}}]}}]
```

Apparently abscissas are represented on a log scale here.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to indicate the coordinate of the intersection point between the vertical line and the curve. How to do that automatically without any hand calculation before?

Comment: Hi again, I still can't do it. I run the code but it doesn't show the coordinate of intersection point something like (10, 0) on the plot. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
g[s_] = 1/(1 + s/10 + s^2/100);

pt1 = {10, Log10[g[10.]]}

(*  {10, -0.477121}  *)

pt2 = {10, Arg[g[I 10.]]/Degree}

(*  {10, -90.}  *)

BodePlot[1/(1 + s/10 + s^2/100),
 Epilog -> {
   {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Tooltip[Point[{1, pt1[[2]]}],
     pt1]},
   {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
    Tooltip[Point[{1, pt2[[2]]}],
     pt2]}},
 GridLines -> {{{10}, None}, {{10}, None}},
 GridLinesStyle -> Red]
```

[image]