# How to plot points on Bode plot curves

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I used `BodePlot` to plot the magnitude and phase plots for a transfer function `Gp1` and I figured out how to add a point to the magnitude (top) plot that is on/follows the curve with: 
`{x,20 Log10@Abs[Gp1/.s->I x]}` but how can I do this for the phase (bottom) plot?

[image]

The transfer function I used is:

```
Gp1 = kc*kp*Exp[-t*s]*(tauI*s + 1)*(tauD*s + 1)/((tauP*s + 1)*tauI*s);
Gp2=TransferFunctionModel[{{Gp1}},s];
t = 1; tauP = 2; tauI = 1; tauD = 3; kp = 8.6; kc = 1;
```

Comment: Can you include the exact code that generated your plots?

Comment: possible duplicate Q/A: [Draw line and point into a BodePlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132617/125)

Answer (score 1):

Modifying [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/132619/125) in [this possible duplicate Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132617/125):

```
BodePlot[Gp2, {.1, 100}, GridLines -> {{{1}, None}, {{1}, None}}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Red, Mesh -> {{{1}}, {{1}}}, 
 MeshStyle -> PointSize[Large], ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]